# mutt: open reply to a message

Tags: email, configuration, mutt

I am trying to find a way in mutt to jump to my reply to a mail.
To be precise: I have a mail from someone else open in mutt and I replied to that mail - a copy of that reply is in the sent folder. Now I want mutt to show me that reply, when I press some key while reading the original message.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,
Prof. MAAD

Comment: Seems like a superuser question to me...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in your .muttrc:

fcc-hook .* =inbox

should place all outgoing mail to your inbox, IMHO. Then you'll see both sent and received messages in one thread.

Comment: better fcc-hook .* !

Answer (score 0):

If the mails were in the same mailbox, you could just sort by threads, and the reply would follow the original mail.

This isn't easy to do when the mails are in different mailboxes. You can try writing a mutt macro that does one of the following:

1. copy the current message to your Sent folder, then switch to the Sent folder, sort by threads, find the first message not sent by you, delete it and go to the next message. This assumes that your sent folder only ever contains messages sent by you.
2. alternatively, filter the current message to a script that writes the Message-ID line to tempfilename, then switch to the sent folder, and limit to message id with `tempfilename`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`sup`](http://sup.rubyforge.org), which is very similar to mutt but it sorts messages like `gmail` (plus other goodies). Also, in the system, you have the sent mailbox separated from other folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [metoo](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#metoo) option and then sort by threads

```
set metoo=yes
set sort="threads"
set sort_aux="reverse-date-received"
```

If you're using [notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org/), there's a very nice feature which rebuilds a thread not matter where the mails are (sent, archived, inbox,...).
Look at notmuch-mutt in the contrib folder.